# Consuming SOAP webservice - null response

Tags: iphone, web-services, soap, null, response

In my iPhone project, I have to consume webservices (public - no need
of authentication) for most of the data that I have to display to the
users.

I am struck with retreiving the data, I am pretty sure that the xml
request I send is true, But I wonder why I am getting the (null)
response, But it says that xxx number of bytes has been received.

Surprisingly one or two webmethods works well, I dont say any
difference either in their definition in WSDL document.

I have checked the same webservices using android code, it works very
well for all the webmethods.

I also had a discussion with the server side developer (who has
written webservices using SOAP protocol), he said that both the
request and the response is true (he can trace the logs of the
requests when I called ). But couldnt able to figure out why I am
getting null.

It is neither throwing any exception nor showing any fault in the
request and I dont have any build or runtime warning

Thankyou in anticipation

Comment: Does the connectionDidFinishLoading method get called? If yes, what is the size of data that you get there? Is it non-zero?

Comment: Yes, It gets called, size is some hundreds of bytes. When I init a string with the Data I received and NSLog of the string gives response as (null). Thankyou

Comment: If the same response in android converts to string successfully, maybe you there is a problem in your string conversion code in iOS. Post the code where you convert the data into string.