# Conversion of NSMutableData to JSON or Dictionary in Objective C /iPhone App Program?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, json, web-services, soap

Conversion of NSMutableData to JSON or Dictionary in Objective C /iPhone App Program?

The NSMutableData that I get is the response from a webservice,

I can convert it easily to NSString, as there is a method - initWithBytes..

But I see the response to be (null).

Since the response actually is in JSON format, can I conver the NSMutableData into JSON using some method or including some framework. (The protocol for the webservice is written in SOAP)

Thanks in advance..

Comment: possible duplicate of [json parsing+iphone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6408413/json-parsingiphone)

Comment: Let me explain my problem. I have to consume webservices (SOAP), only two of the webmethods are responding, the rest of them are not responding. I discussed with the server side person to check wsdl and try tracing the request, he told that after tracing - both the request and response's are true and ofcourse there is no difference in the method definitions. But either of us didnt understand why I am getting a null response for the rest of the webmethods ? Basically we are getting the response in NSMutable Data of some number of bytes(for non-working methods), We tried converting to JSON/Dict

Comment: Edit your post to include the string returned.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting your data as plain JSON in a coherent form, you can use [this library on Github (JSONKit)](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) to map your JSON strings to objects/dictionaries.

It's a very convenient and easy way to handle JSON. Advantages this library brings are listed on the Github page.

Comment: Yup, I used the JSONKit, But I still get the dictionary/array as null with 0 elements in it. But I am able to see the number of bytes received. I am a beginner in this. Please explain and help me. Thankyou very much.

Comment: Well it's hard for me to help you without the code. And I imagine it's not easy for you to just post a little piece as it's most likely gonna be longer than a couple lines. - Let's presume that JSONKit works flawlessly in all cases when supplied a JSON string. Then the only way it's gonna generate null is if the supplied string is syntactically incorrect OR the JSONKit is used in a wrong manner. Thus double check your JSON _and_ doublecheck the tutorial on JSONKit.

Comment: I tried using sudzc.com,  It also gave me same (null) response for non working methods. Ofcourse the working methods gave me correct response. Please see my comment below my question for greater details of my question. Do you people think that there is any issues with wsdl or any issues from server side ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727239/consuming-soap-webservice-null-response

Answer (score 0):

You can use the well-documented [`NSJSONSerialization` class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to do this. It comes with Foundation.

Comment: That's true, but the question said nothing about backwards compatibility.

Comment: I know.  It wasn't intended as a criticism of your answer, just extra information.

Comment: Please look above to better understand my issue. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727239/consuming-soap-webservice-null-response